# ExtJs : Sencha Help Document

Tags: extjs

I am working on developing help document, this is based on bunch of html pages that we already have, from the our old CHM help.

## I would like to know how you construct the database for the search engine.?

Is it that you scan the data from the static html pages or do you get the metadata from the code documentation tags.

Comment: You may want to use [jsduck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck), which automatically generates everything from your ExtJS project javadoc-style annotations, including the search index.

Comment: i cannot use that, because actually i am creating the user help for our solution. So i want to re-utilize the existing html help files that we have for the old CHM.